# Lubuntu 20.04 LTS ignores boot parameter "union=aufs"

Tags: boot, system-installation, lubuntu

I'm trying to boot a live usb with the boot parameter "union=aufs", the system boots but the directory "/" is an overlay mount point, not aufs. In order for me to implement some things, I really need the root of the filesystem to be an aufs mount point. Has ubuntu removed "union=aufs" option from live cd/usb?
Here are my boot parameters:

/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper union=aufs file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed iso-scan/filename=/_ISO/LINUX/MNU/lubuntu-20.04.3/64bits/lubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso quiet splash --

Comment: I'll suggest reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash#AUFS_support_in_main_line_kernel "*Various unsuccessful attempts have been made to include aufs in the mainline kernel. The Ubuntu kernel has been supporting it, but there is a strong movement to drop support and use overlayfs instead.*"

Comment: I had read this text before, it was written around the time of ubuntu 12.04, but the ubuntu 14.04 I was using still supported the "union=aufs" parameter so the system root was an aufs mount point. The Lubuntu 20.04 LTS kernel still supports aufs. I'm not sure, but it looks like it no longer supports having the system root be an aufs mount point.